# Prove that $P_x(x)$ is indeed a probability mass function.

Tags: probability, random-variables

The random variable $X$ has the probability mass function given as
$$P_x(x) = \frac{\binom{k}{x}\binom{N-k}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}, x=0, ..., k$$

where $n, k, N$ are all integers, and satisfy
$$k<n , N>n+k$$

Prove that $P_x(x)$ is indeed a probability mass function,
i.e.,
$$\sum_{x=0}^k P_x(x) = 1$$ (Hint. Argue
or show that
$$\binom{N}{n} = \sum_{x=0}^k\binom{k}{x}\binom{N-k}{n-x}$$)

Comment: Nice HW exercise. What have you tried?

Comment: We expanded the sum from sigma 0 to k, but the expression became more complex.

Comment: Can you please add this to your post then? As it stands your question will receive downvotes and eventually be closed as it does not meet site standards.

Comment: okay. this is my post. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KZlgEOYhzPHpCmIn7bdy5-eHgDuEC8E_/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{x = 0}^{k} \frac{{k\choose x} {N -k \choose n - x} }{{N\choose n}} = \frac{1}{{N\choose n}} \sum_{x = 0}^{k} {k\choose x} {N -k \choose n - x} = \frac{1}{{N\choose n}} {N\choose n} = 1
$$

where the penusltimate equality follows from the identity provided (called Vandermonde's Identity)

To complete the proof we also need to show that it is non-negative which follows easily fromthe fact that the binomial coefficient is always non-negative.